# Proof that $-(-A) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have tried to prove that, given a set $A$, $-(-A)=A$. Are there flaws in my logic? I am very new to proof writing and set theory so any tips on structuring the proof would be greatly appreciated. My proof is:

> If $S$ is the space and $A\subset S$, then $-(-A)=S-(-A)$.
>
> Suppose that $x \in S-(-A) \iff x \notin-A \iff x\notin S-A \iff x\in A. $ Therefore, $-(-A)=A$

My main queries with my proof are:

1)Is it necessary to introduce the space $S$ and state $-(-A)=S-(-A)$?

2)Is my use of $\iff$ correct?

Comment: It seems to be $\;-A\;$ is, in your notation, *complement* of set $\;A\;$ ...right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Then I've no idea why you write $;-(-A)=S-(-A)\;$ ... The notation I think is the most standard one is $\;-A= S\setminus A\;$ , or if you prefer, $\;-A=S-A\;$ . Thus, we'd have $\;-(-A)=S-(S-A)\;$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by $-A$ you understand the complement of $A$ in $S$, i.e. we assume that $A\subseteq S$ and $$-A=S-A=\{x\in S\ |\ x\not\in A\}$$

> Is it necessary to introduce the space $S$?

Yes, $-A$ is not well defined without the set it is living in. For example if $A=\{1\}$ and $S=A$ then $-A=\emptyset$. But if $S=\{1,2\}$ then $-A=\{2\}$. So as you can see the final result depends on $S$.

However some properties are independent on $S$. And $-(-A)$ is one of them. No matter what $S$ is $-(-A)=A$.

> Is my use of $\iff$ correct?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way out:

$$x\in A\implies x\notin -A\implies x\in-(-A)\implies A\subset -(-A)$$

and on the other hand

$$x\in-(-A)\implies x\notin -A\implies x\in A\implies -(-A)\subset A$$

Comment: If you replace $\Rightarrow$ with $\iff$ (which you can do, except for the last $\Rightarrow$ which is not necessary) you will get exactly what OP's done but in a single line. So how exactly is that "an easy way out"?

Comment: @freakish As noted in my comment, the OP used incorrectly the notation $\;-(-A)=S-(-A)\;$ . I thought he was having problems wrapping his mind around complements so I did it here in two steps. Imo, way clearer and easier to grasp. That's the "easy way out" .

Comment: What exactly is incorrect in $-(-A)=S-(-A)$? It might not be standard but it is definitely correct. And formally it is even more correct (assuming something can be more correct) then your answer which doesn't take $S$ into account (which is formally incorrect).

Comment: @freakish Assuming what he said he did, we have that $\;-A=S-A\;$ , and thus $\;-(-A)=S-(S-A)\;$ . This can be a huge confusion, though apparently the OP understood it well. So no: I wouldn't say $\;-(-A)=S-(-A)\;$ **after** it is understood complements must be taken with respect to some other, bigger set. OTOH, you telling the OP that his use of $\;\iff\;$ is correct could induce him to think his notation was correct...and it wasn't.